# Linux command to remove multiple files with two dot in the file name

Tags: linux, rm

Example file names is

> abc.edf.xdc
>   pqe.ide.xdc

`rm -rf "*.\*.xdc"` is not working

Comment: Do you need this to remove all files that contain **exactly** two dots?

Answer (score 5):

Drop the quotes and it works:

```
/tmp/a$ touch abc.edf.xdc pqe.ide.xdc
/tmp/a$ ls
abc.edf.xdc  pqe.ide.xdc
/tmp/a$ rm -f *.*.xdc
/tmp/a$ ls
/tmp/a$
```

Answer (score 3):

`rm -rf *.xdc` should match all of those files.  There's no need to put the extra "*.".

Comment: Unless he wants to specifically remove the ones with at least 2 dots, but you are right I didn't consider that he may believe this is needed :)

Comment: @CMoi I believe that _*.*.xdc_ also matches _foo.bar.more.dots.in.here.xdc_, as the * takes whatever text is in there, including dots.

Comment: Yes it does, which is why I said "at least 2 dots"

Comment: @CMoi yes, you are right :)  In that case, neither of the responses ensure that the files being removed contained _exactly_ two dots...  :-p

Answer (score 1):

Source `man bash`

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of
>   all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and, when history  expansion  is  enabled,  !. The characters $ and `
>   retain their special meaning within double quotes.

So you don't need to use double quotes, just give `rm -vf *.*.xdc`